# Using shapeless to implement filter

Tags: scala, filter, shapeless

I'm trying to implement a filter such as the one described in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/yakticus/4622facd96ac6bdf17cf) (please see the last comment).

I want to wrap the salad bowl into a Fruits class, like this:

```
scala> class Fruits[L <: HList](val bowl: FruitBowl[L])
```

I then want to create multiple fruits in a list, like this:

```
scala> val fruits = List(new Fruits(new FruitBowl(Apple() :: Pear() :: HNil)), new Fruits(new FruitBowl(Pear() :: HNil)))
```

Then I just want to get the apple parts of each fruits, so I try to filter :

```
scala> fruits.map(_.bowl.getAll[Apple])
```

But then I get the following error :

```
<console>:16: error: could not find implicit value for parameter pf: shapeless.ops.hlist.Partition[_2,Apple]
   fruits.map(_.bowl.getAll[Apple])
```

But I though the Partition was supposed to be generic so I see no reason why it shouldn't be used...

I don't understand what's going on here with the implicits. Any idea of what's going wrong ?

Comment: I think the issue is with the type of `fruits`, which loses precision

Comment: As @GabrielePetronella says, when you use `List` it widens the type of it's elements to find the common bound, so `fruits` has type `List[Fruits[HList]]`, all the information about the exact `L <: HList` types is lost and there's no implicit that could filter/partition an unknown `HList`.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer. I think I understood what you are saying and I'll be trying to work with a HList of HList to simulate the behaviour I want.

Comment: Actually that was not possible at compile-time since the lists are dynamycally sized :). So you're both right!